# Adding a javascript variable to html 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add some JavaScript into my HTML.

I have a JavaScript variable. How can I add it to my HTML code?

```
<a href="index.php?something=MYJAVASCRIPT VARIABLE">
```

---

**UPDATE:** Tried this:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="window.location.href = 'index.php?month=' +thisyear+'-1-1'" rel="external"> Jan </a>
```

But it's not working for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can propably use something like :

```
  <a href="#"
     onclick="window.location.href='index.php?something='+yourJavascriptVariable"/>
```

Comment: Please note that it is not `onclick="javascript:window.location.href=` but rather `onclick="window.location.href=`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the js contents of the variable into a `$_GET` parameter for PHP to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = 'THIS_IS_MY_JS_CONTENT';
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'something.php?variable=' + myvar">Variable</a>
```

View it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/kmquk/

Comment: Trying this but there's an error somewhere ? As it's not working: <a href="#"  onclick="javascript:window.location.href = 'index.php?month=' +thisyear+'2011-1-1'" rel="external"> Jan </a>

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.document.location = 'index.php?month=' + thisyear + '2011-1-1'" rel="external"> Jan </a>`

Answer (score -1):

you may write it like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and your js is `<head>`

```
$(function(){
  var name = "Pr0fess0rX";
  $("#content").html("<div><h3>" + name + "</h3></div>");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give ID to `h3` tag or find it by jQuery and give value of variable to `innerText` property of found control.

For example `<div><h3 id="mytagID"></h3></div>`

```
function DoSomething() {
   var myTag = document.getElementById("mytagID");
   myTag.innerText = myvariableValue;
}
```